# Complex Polars Operation Using Subqueries and Threshold first hits

Tags: python, algorithm, python-polars

`df_original` represents the ice-cream inspector on station `A` and `B`:

```py
df_original = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "station": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
        "ice_cream_date": [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        "customers": [10, 20, 30, 5, 5, 7, 4, 10],
        "event": [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    }
)
```

- `ice_cream_date` is the date encoded.
- `customers` represents the number of customers
- `event` represents the binary encoding where an inspector

`df_evnets` is where `event == 1` in `df_original`:

```py
df_events =  pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "events": [1, 1, 1, 1],
        "ice_cream_date": [2, 4, 1, 3],
        "station": ["A", "A", "B", "B"],
        "customers": [20, 5, 5, 4],
        "evaluation_span": [10, 2, 2, 2],
        "evaluation_end_date": [4, 4, 3, 4],
        "evaluation_end_date_customer": [5, 5, 4, 10],
        "good_customer": [30, 10, 8, 12],
        "bad_customer": [5, 0, 4, 3],
    }
)
```

- `evaluation_span` is the number of days after the inspection date
- `evaluation_end_date` is the latest day for the inspection. (if the date+evaluation_span > max available date, the evaluation_end_date is the max available date.)
- `evaluation_end_date_customer` is the number of customers at the `evaluation_end_date` in `df_original`
- `good_customer` is the good threshold for an inspector to give the station "good" rating on a particular `ice_cream_date`
- `bad_customer`: the bad threshold

**Struggling with:**
I want to label whether a station has being given `good` or `bad` rating for every non-zero event.

**If an inspector sees the number of customers exceeds(dips below) the good(bad) threshold first, the station will be given good(bad) rating no matter of the length of the event span**

Expected output:

```py
shape: (4, 7)
┌────────────────┬─────────┬────────────────────┬──────┬─────┬────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ ice_cream_date ┆ station ┆ evaluation_custome ┆ good ┆ bad ┆ evaluation_end ┆ actual_evaluation_ │
│ ---            ┆ ---     ┆ rs                 ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---            ┆ end_date           │
│ i64            ┆ str     ┆ ---                ┆ i64  ┆ i64 ┆ i64            ┆ ---                │
│                ┆         ┆ i64                ┆      ┆     ┆                ┆ i64                │
╞════════════════╪═════════╪════════════════════╪══════╪═════╪════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 2              ┆ A       ┆ 30                 ┆ 1    ┆ 0   ┆ 0              ┆ 3                  │
│ 4              ┆ A       ┆ 5                  ┆ 0    ┆ 0   ┆ 1              ┆ 4                  │
│ 1              ┆ B       ┆ 4                  ┆ 0    ┆ 1   ┆ 1              ┆ 3                  │
│ 3              ┆ B       ┆ 10                 ┆ 0    ┆ 0   ┆ 1              ┆ 4                  │
└────────────────┴─────────┴────────────────────┴──────┴─────┴────────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

- `evaluation_customers` is the number of customers used for the evaluation
- `good` is the good binary label, indicating that during the `(event_date, event_date+evaluation_span]`, whether an inspector gives good rating to a station for a particular inspection event.
- `bad` is the bad binary label.
- `evaluation_end` is the evaluation end label, indicating that the number of customers did not exceeds(dips below) the good(bad) threshold during `(event_date, event_date+span)`
- `actual_evaluation_end_date` is the date where the evaluation ends (good or bad threshold reached)

[image]

Comment: It's not clear how this is supposed to work. Take station A on date=2, there were 20 customers but your expected output has 30 evaluation_customers.

Comment: I'd suggest you to simplify your example to narrow down the problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @RomanPekar in principle, I, of course, agree that minimal examples are better. In this case there are (what seem to be) superfluous columns but more importantly is that there seems to be a hidden piece of logic to get from input to output. Getting that logic articulated is, at this point, more important than shrinking *this particular question* down.

Comment: @Roman Pekar @Dean MacGregor Thank you very much for your questions & comments. I have added an explaination graph and hopefully it will clear the things out.

For `Station A` on `date=2`, there were 20 customers at station A and thats where the inspection begins, the inspection spans (2, 12], and because of the max avaliable date is 4, the span becomes (2, 4], the good and bad evaluation `tau` is then set up. For [date=3, date=4], the inspector is going to check whether the good or bad tau is reached, if yes then good & bad eval is given. For `StationA` and `date=3` -> good & 30 customers

Comment: The `Station A` `date=2` event spans (2, 12] and due to the date avaliability constraint it becomes (2, 4] is reflected on the `evaluation_end_date` col